# FBSDKCoreKit lacks support for BitCode

Tags: ios, facebook, cocoapods

I just added the facebook pod `pod 'Facebook-iOS-SDK'` to our project, but when building it, it fails due to lack of Bitcode support.

Our project has to run with Bitcode enabled.

Any advice, please?

> ld:
>   '/Users/houmie/projects/tegant/Pods/Facebook-iOS-SDK/FacebookSDKs-iOS-universal-4.37.0/iOS/FBSDKCoreKit.framework/FBSDKCoreKit(FBSDKGraphRequestPiggybackManager.o)'
>   does not contain bitcode. You must rebuild it with bitcode enabled
>   (Xcode setting ENABLE_BITCODE), obtain an updated library from the
>   vendor, or disable bitcode for this target. file
>   '/Users/houmie/projects/xxx/Pods/Facebook-iOS-SDK/FacebookSDKs-iOS-universal-4.37.0/iOS/FBSDKCoreKit.framework/FBSDKCoreKit'
>   for architecture arm64 clang: error: linker command failed with exit
>   code 1 (use -v to see invocation)

Comment: I have the same issue after updating to latest FBSDK... Did you find a solution?

Comment: No, best is to downgrade to 4.36. It has been Two weeks since FB acknowledged this and still hasn't provided a fix.

Comment: That's what I did, thanks!

Comment: Joshua FYI, Facebook fixed the bitcode issue:

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/ios/

also you need to update to Xcode 10